# CKEditor inside jQuery modal issue with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor 4.4.7 the problem is when I open my modal dialog witch contains CKEditor and I'm trying to use Background Color or Text Color buttons and if I didn't choose any color from the list and close it, afterwards I receive in console error:

> TypeError: a.contentWindow is null  TypeError:
>   this.*.panel.*.iframe.getFrameDocument(...).getById(...) is null

and these buttons are not working anymore, whenever I try to press them they wont open any menu again until I will not refresh page..

This is code for my modal dialog.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <textarea id='editor1' name='editor1'></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    </script>
    <input type="submit" name="submitComment" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What's the problem and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the problem described here:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-t-edit-fields-of-ckeditor-in-jquery-ui-modal-dialog#14737000005423723
and here:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:30 (the solution described here does not seem to work anymore).

My solution was the following:

```
orig_allowInteraction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
$.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(event){
    // address interaction issues with general iframes with the dialog
    if (event.target.ownerDocument != this.document[0]){
        return true;
    }
    // address interaction issues with dialog window
    if ($(event.target).closest(".cke_dialog").length){
        return true;
    }
    // address interaction issues with iframe based drop downs in IE
    if ($(event.target).closest(".cke").length){
        return true;
    }
    return orig_allowInteraction.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This solution is not perfect as I got 'too much recursion' errors in Firefox, but it works for the most part. If you are having a different problem I apologise.